# Does the Stack Exchange Android app have all the features of the website?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, ios-app, android-app

Does the Stack Exchange mobile app(mainly Android app) have all the features of the website? I am trying to explore but it seems some features are not there. Like the flagging queue etc. Can anyone help me where can I find all guidance?

Comment: Queue (Review) is not there on the mobile version of the site too. While flagging exists and is in the "$\cdots$ More" tab as well as closing. If you want to flag a comment you select it and in the top right corner select the 3 vertical dots there is flag.

Comment: @kingW3 I know flag is in mobile version... I am just saying I think not every feature are in mobile app... is that true?? more generally a navigation for mobile app would be helpful.

Comment: I'm talking about the mobile app. Though mobile app is just way too confusing. Following my comment above you can see how to flag a question/answer/comment (in the mobile app).

Comment: I guess adding ([meta-tag:ios-app]) or ([meta-tag:android-app]) to this question would be reasonable thing to do. (Or both, if the question is about both of them.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. SE mobile app doesn't have many features that the mobile/desktop web already has. Personally (though many have voiced the same opinion), the only useful thing is its push notification.

You can see the most-voted, open feature requests for Android SE app on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+feature-request+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-review+-status-reproduced?sort=votes), like:

- [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216962)
- [Add review queues to Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215841)
- [Allow us to vote to reopen from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233669)
- [Add the revision history to the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228440)
- [Favorited Tag Questions on the Stack Exchange Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201593)
- [Favorite questions in the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229658)
- and much more...

iOS counterpart has more love, [though it's still not perfect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app+feature-request+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-review+-status-reproduced?sort=votes):

- [Are the review queues planned for the iOS app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231492)
- [Ability to modify profile on iOS app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230093)
- [Allow adding bounties from the iOS & Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243346)
- [Vote to reopen in the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245753)
- [Show post(s) already chosen as duplicate suggestions in iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277933)
- and more...

Some of them are caused by [the limitation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api+feature-request+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-review+-status-reproduced?sort=votes) of [SE API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) that is used as the back-end of these mobile apps.